# Configure CloudFront distribution with Origin server for static content only

Tags: server, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have run in to a problem while setting up my CloudFront.

What I want to do is to create a CDN for my images only that are hosted on my own server rather than S3 bucket. So the directory on the server with all the images is at `mysite.org/images/` which if accessed directly without the file name should kick 404 error instead of 403. Now the way I need it to be set up is, for example someone accessing a page on my site `misite.org/wedding/georgetown.html` or `misite.org/wedding/london.html` all images that are served on those pages should come from location `cdn.mysite.org/wedding/images/`, which if accessed directly without the file name should serve 403 error.

So what I have done so far that pretty much did not get me anywhere is, I set up cloudfront distribution that points to my origin server `mysite.org`, but now the entire site is accessible via `cdn.mysite.org` and `mysite.org`, which is not really what I was trying to achieve.

Any help or suggestions please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do,

Create multiple origins,

In the Behaviour enter pattern to,

map, `/images/*` to  `cdn.mysite.org/wedding/images/`   for your static resources

while rest of them come from different origin.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Kannaiyan, thanks for your answer, I have tried it this way and mapped /images/* to the origin server, but it did not work, I only get 404 for every request.

Comment: 404 is coming from origin. Make sure you have the right origin pointed to the behaviour.